# EXPLAIN (BUFFER,ANALYZE) understading

Tags: performance, postgresql, database

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3
Can some one help me what i can do to improve this.
The max number of records in db table is approx 5000 to 7000 varies daily basis.
shared_buffers setting in PGsql DB is =1GB.
whats wrong here.
My query o/p is
QUERY PLAN

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..10873.44 rows=75 width=271) (actual time=0.123..51.515 rows=3982 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=18475 read=55682
   Index Scan using idx_chrghist_picked_status on charge_history  (cost=0.42..10239.13 rows=75 width=255) (actual time=0.092..16.022 rows=3982 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (picked_status = 'NOTPICKED'::text)
         Filter: ((updated_date)::date = (('now'::cstring)::date - 1))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 10022
         Buffers: shared hit=2547 read=55682
    Index Scan using "CUSTOMERID" on subscriber_data  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=3982)
         Index Cond: ((customer_id)::text = (charge_history.customer_id)::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=15928
Total runtime: 52.053 ms
```

Query :

```
EXPLAIN (BUFFERS,ANALYZE)
SELECT
  subscriber_data.customer_id ,
  charge_history.charge_trx_id,
  charge_history.updated_date,
  charge_history.command_tx_id ,
  charge_history.mvno_id,
  charge_history.customer_id,
  charge_history.extra_plan_id,
  charge_history.base_plan_id,
  charge_history.old_base_plan_id,
  charge_history.volume,
  charge_history.price,
  charge_history.charge_type,
  charge_history.remarks
FROM charge_history , subscriber_data
WHERE subscriber_data.customer_id=charge_history.customer_id
  AND charge_history.updated_date::date=(CURRENT_DATE - integer '1')
  AND 'charge_history.picked_status = 'NOTPICKED';
```

Answer (score 0):

This query run in 52ms, probably not much. It's two index scans and a nested loop and it returns 3,982 rows.

You could perhaps not use `text`, or set `NOTPICKED` to `null` (if that column doesn't already use null).